# What is load frequency and refresh frequency in Data warehouse?

Tags: data-warehouse

What is load frequency and refresh frequency in Data warehouse? How are they differentiated?

Answer (score 1):

There are for sure lot of possible interpretation, one of them I'd suggest is that the **Load** describes adding (`INSERT`) new transactions in a fact table. **Refresh** is a job that updates a dimension to the new state (which may consist of `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and (logical) `DELETE`).

The *frequency* is defined with the periodicity those jobs are scheduled.

Anyway with similar argumentation you may deduce that both terms are synonyms, so take care with the interpretation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now, the things are getting clearer.

Comment: I've never seen these differentiated, so we're clutching at straws here.

Comment: I came across the following point in dwbi.org and was confused. That made me ask this question.

 "Data warehouse’s data loading frequency does not match with the refresh frequencies of the source systems." 

https://dwbi.org/etl/etl/52-why-do-we-need-staging-area-during-etl-load

Comment: Quote: *Data warehouse’s data loading frequency does not match with the refresh frequencies of the source systems*, well this is stating nothing else than the source system and a DWH are processed independently. Note that the *refresh frequency* is related to the source system, not to the DWH.